# Create a column by Groupy and filter in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have a data frame with vendor, bill amount, and payment type.

[image]

I want to add a column in which I will get sum of late payment by Vendor.

[image]

Is it be possible to write one line code to get this output?

df['Paid Late by Vendor']=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define the dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Vendor':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'Payment':['Ontime', 'Delay', 'Ontime', 'Delay'],
        'Paid Late by Vendor':[20, 21, 19, 18]})
```

to get the results you want you need to create a separate dataframe with grouped values and then combine it with the original.

Since you want a value for only late payments then you need to filter the data to-be-grouped to have only the wanted records, and group on it.
`reset_index()` is used to make the index a column(in this case it's the column that we grouped on; Vendor)

```
groupedLateData = data[data['Payment']=='Delay'].groupby('Vendor')["Paid Late by Vendor"].sum().reset_index()
```

Then we merge the resulting dataframe with the original on the Vendor column

```
pd.merge(data, groupedLateData, on='Vendor')
```

and this would be the result: [image: result]

Comment: Can it be possible to write one line code to get the result?                                                                  df['Paid Late by Vendo']=...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `groupby.transform` and `bfill()`, and assign back to a new column using `assign`:

```
df = df.assign(late_payments=df[df['Payment'].eq('Delay')].groupby('Vendor')['Amount'].transform('sum')).bfill()
```

Prints:

```
  Vendor Payment  Amount  late_payments
0      A  Ontime      91           78.0
1      A  Ontime      90           78.0
2      A   Delay      78           78.0
3      B  Ontime      58          166.0
4      B   Delay      77          166.0
5      B  Ontime      96          166.0
6      B   Delay      89          166.0
```